# how to left join array without printing left join 10 times?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, join

I have 2 tables in PostgreSQL
Table 1 columns: user_id, date,p. Where p is array with 10 elements. In this table information in p column is "coded" by numbers. We can Encrypt it using Table 2: which has 2 columns: id (this is numbers from Table1.p[i]) and value (this is real values)

To encrypt values from Table1.p i user left_join 10 times.
For Example

```
Select * from Table1 left join Table2
on Table1.p[1]=Table2.id 
left join  Table2
on Table1.p[2]=Table2.id
left join  Table2
on Table1.p[3]=Table2.id
....
left join  Table2
on Table1.p[10]=Table2.id;
```

Can i somehow join full array, without printing left join 1 times?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do, but I think you are looking for this:

```
Select * 
from Table1 
  left join Table2 on table2.id = any(Table1.p);
```